# can't use CSplitbutton giving compilation error

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack

i can not use CSplitbutton in MFC dialog based application it gives declaration error.
i include afxwin.h but giving same problem.

please help i am in deadlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please enable Unicode setting in your project.
CSplitbutton has unicode dependency.
as given below

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x600) && defined(UNICODE)
  class CSplitButton : public CButton
```

as per above code your version required vista + and enable unicode setting.

Comment: Odd thing; I had the same issue, looked it up in my own afxwin.h, and while yes the `#if`does ask for UNICODE, the `#endif` comment is `// (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x600) && defined(CSplitButton)`. There is definitely a typo here, are you certain it is not in the `#if` line? (My afxwin.h is last modified on 05.June.2013)